# swift images array code back button error

Tags: ios, swift

I want to slide from the pictures. My code is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
var resimler=["01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg"]
var index=0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBAction func gerileBttn(sender: UIButton) {

    index--

   if index==resimler.count {index=0}
    image.image=UIImage(named: resimler[index])
} 

@IBAction func ilerle(sender: UIButton) {

    index++
    if index==resimler.count {index=0}
    image.image=UIImage(named: resimler[index])
}
```

When I press forward moving pictures. However, when it comes to the first picture when I press the back key "array" error whether the program crashes.. 
How can I solve this problem. 
Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your index may be going negative. Perhaps this (assuming you want it to wrap)?

```
@IBAction func gerileBttn(sender: UIButton) {

    index--

   if index<0 {index=resimler.count-1}
    image.image=UIImage(named: resimler[index])
}
```